# Vertical align top in multicolumn

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multicolumn

I have this table, and I want the 'A' to be vertically aligned at the top.

[image]

```
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{ \Large{A} }} & B \\
    & & C \\
    D & E & F  \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Bla bla}
\end{table}
```

I assume I have to put a `[t]` somewhere, but I am at loss as to where...

Answer (score 5):

An optional parameter for vertical alignment in `multirow` has been [recently added](http://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.1275.1475076592.1426.ctan-ann@ctan.org).

This way with the `t` vertical alignment options and some `fine tunning`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow[t]{2}{*}[-.77ex]{\Large{A}}} & B \\
    & & C \\
    D & E & F  \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Bla bla}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to position the A explicitly with `\raisebox` (after all, it's a visual decision where the A looks best). Modify `1ex` to move the A. Side-note: `\Large` is a declaration and takes no argument. `\Large{A}` is the same as `\Large A`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\raisebox{-1ex}[0ex][0ex]{\Large A}} & B \\
  & & C \\
  D & E & F  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That works, but I am not sure if I understand why we can do without the `\multirow{}` all of a sudden (but `\raisebox{}` is new to me, so that might explain...)

Comment: @Tom Well, I wouldn't think of `\multirow` for such simple applications; `\raisebox` is "standard" LaTeX, and quite useful in many situations, not just tabulars. The trick is that the A overlaps with the cells below; because its height and depth is 0, it is "invisible" regarding the height of the first row and doesn't influence it. See [LaTeX/Boxes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes) for a description of `\raisebox` and instructive examples.

Answer (score 2):

A small variation of Ignasi answer:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}[0.7pt]{\Large{A}}} & B \\
    & & C \\
    D & E & F  \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Bla bla}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that your solution forces that `A` and `B` lay on one row, while Tom wants `A` top aligned but it can also occupy part of second row.

Comment: Yes. I observe, that `multirow` actually centered its content to number of lines in other columns. Select one line (row) only is not intuitive, but force that `multirov` push its content to the top of its cell. For proof make a test with `\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}[0.7pt]{\Large{A}}} & B \\`.  Frankly said, before your nice answer I didn't observe the possibility for options `[t]`. Is this new with recent `multirow` version?  it seems that your approach is more correct than mine

Comment: The addition of this vertical option to multirow was done at end of september: http://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.1275.1475076592.1426.ctan-ann@ctan.org